# UIButtons not sticking to UIView edges

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

Hi and thanks in advance. I'm attempting to bind two UIButtons to a `UIViewController`'s `view` like so:

First by declaring them:

```
fileprivate var deleteButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)
fileprivate var addButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```

Next in setting them up:

```
private func setupButtons() {

    deleteButton.setTitle("Delete", for: .normal)
    addButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)

    deleteButton.sizeToFit()
    addButton.sizeToFit()

    deleteButton.alpha = 1
    addButton.alpha = 1

    view.addSubview(deleteButton)
    view.addSubview(addButton)

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: deleteButton,
                                          attribute: .leading,
                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: view,
                                          attribute: .leading,
                                          multiplier: 1.0,
                                          constant: 0))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: deleteButton,
                                          attribute: .bottom,
                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: view,
                                          attribute: .bottom,
                                          multiplier: 1.0,
                                          constant: 0))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton,
                                          attribute: .trailing,
                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: view,
                                          attribute: .trailing,
                                          multiplier: 1.0,
                                          constant: 0))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton,
                                          attribute: .bottom,
                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: view,
                                          attribute: .bottom,
                                          multiplier: 1.0,
                                          constant: 0))

}
```

But running the simulator sticks the two UIButtons in the top left, the default CGRect frames assigned to them both.

Might you know what i'm doing wrong? I feel like i'm close but perhaps it has something to do with re-drawing the view?

[image: Halp!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

```
// before activate constraint

deleteButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Also, you have to set [isActive](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1527000-isactive) = true instead of using [addConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint) method

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what was missing. Would you discuss what is happening here?

Comment: NP. Autoresizing mask constraints fully specify the view’s size and position. If translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints equals true(by default) that mean you couldn't add more constraint without conflicts. That means that your constraints wont work or even crash app. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco).